# Xcode/Swift error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, singleton

I am trying to call a function of a singleton class with completion handler argument but I get "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" error. I am using Xcode 6.2 (6C101) and trying to build for iOS 8 on iPhone 6 simulator. Here is the singlton class:

```
public class ClientManager {

    public class var sharedInstance: ClientManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ClientManager()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    private init() {
    }

    public func fetchServiceInfo(serviceName: String, completionHandler: (JSON?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, Router.ServiceInfo(serviceName)).responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            completionHandler(JSON(json!), error)
        }
    }

}
```

And when I call `fetchServiceInfo` function within a view controller, Xcode crashes (SourceKitService Crashed):

```
ClientManager.sharedInstance.fetchServiceInfo("default") { (json, error) in
    println(json)
}
```

However, if I call the same function within the `init` method of `ClientManager` it works properly:

```
private init() {
    self.fetchServiceInfo("default") { (json, error) in
        println(json)
    }
}
```

I am using `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON` libraries.

Comment: Are you by chance using the SwiftyJSON framework? Meaning not just taking a copy of the file. I've been unable to use the JSON object as a parameter when I use the framework. If I make a copy of the file and add it into my project though it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes! I had it as framework before, but now I have it as a swift file in my project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

¿Is posible you are using SwiftyJSON as framework, cocoapods or git submodule? Look at https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/125
Using SwiftyJSON.swift file into your project must work fine

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As Carlos Garcia correctly pointed out, the problem is with compiling SwiftyJSON. In his provided link https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/125, check the solution by nunogoncalves. In a nutshell, you MUST use the closure JSON parameter at least once in the closure body. Here is what I did:

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.loadOrderDetails(187, onComplete: { (json, errorMessage) -> () in
    json?["aaa"] //this useless line fixes the compiler crash

    //the rest of your code here...
});
```