# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 compile error

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault, xcode7

I spent a lot of time trying to solve that issue myself and already double checked available answers on SO with the same error. So here are the list of thing that I already excluded from possible reasons:

1. No issue with frameworks as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11). I have created another project with the same frameworks set and all is fine
2. No [issue with SwiftyJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604758/xcode-swift-error-command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11), also works fine in test project
3. No compile issues highlighted in the code
4. I went through two different `project.pbxproj` files (from my original project and fresh test project) using comparison tool to find some differences in project settings, all the same
5. I also compared build command options for two projects and all the same

When I go to the Report Navigator and look for each file which wasn't compiled successfully, I found some weird correlation: any file that use some of the API of `NSString` fails to compile. To prove that assumption I found some file which was compiled successfully and added there the following line of code

```
let abc = NSString(string: "abc")
```

and then this file stops to compile too.

So for some files it says that casting `String` class object with `as NSString` is invalid, somewhere `NSAttributedString`/`NSString` creation fails, in some other places calling `compare` or `rangeOfString` was incorrect etc. But when I copy pasted all that pieces of code that caused `Segmentation fault` error to my new fresh project, they compiled successfully

And of course, that project was compiling fine using Xcode 6 just one day ago

I don't know where to go from here and how to fix that issues, any help will be very useful

**UPD**

I uploaded the project that doesn't compile to the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azat92/BrokenSwift)

Comment: `let abc = NSString(string: "abc")` alone compiles (if "Foundation" is imported). Can you provide minimal sample code exhibiting the problem? – In any case, a compiler segmentation fault is a bug and should be reported to Apple.

Comment: @MartinR as I already mentioned, if I create new project, any listed issues go away, all compiles successfully. That happens only on my project that was initially created in the Xcode 6

Comment: @MartinR I cleaned my original project and uploaded to the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azat92/BrokenSwift). Please check it

Comment: For me it was a lengthy function that contained test data array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "MYHelpers.h/.m" of your project (presumably from https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/MYHelpers)
 a `NSString` category with some utility methods is defined:

```
#pragma mark - NSString+Utils

@interface NSString (Utils)
- (NSString *)trim; // trim whitespace characters with new line
- (NSString *):(NSString *)appendString;
- (NSURL *)toURL;
- (NSString *)URLEncodedString;
- (NSString *)URLDecodedString;
- (NSString *)lightURLEncodeString;
+ (BOOL)emailValidate:(NSString *)email;
- (CGSize)sizeForStringWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size;
- (id)JSON;
@end
```

The second method

```
- (NSString *):(NSString *)appendString;
```

has an *empty selector name*. This is allowed in Objective-C,
and you can call the method with

```
NSString *foobar = [@"foo" :@"bar"];
```

(I don't know if the method was intentionally defined with an empty
selector name – I wouldn't recommend it.)

But it causes the *Swift compiler to crash*. This happens only if `NSString`
is referenced somewhere in the Swift code.
(The compiler should never crash, no matter how malformed the input is,
so I would recommend to file a bug report at Apple).

You can rename the method to

```
- (NSString *)appendString:(NSString *)appendString;
```

(or simply remove it if you don't need it in your project),
that  should solve the problem.

Comment: @Azat: Yes, some detective work before I call it a day :)

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same problem in my project. [image: See my screen shot]
**My scenario:**
Find the scenario below in which I had found this bug at my end.
1. I am using my objective- C code in my swift project.
2. Basically It was a **category** class of `UIImage` which I was using in my code.

**Reason of this bug:** As far as I am able to judge that complier was confused with some bit code and it was not able to show exact reason. So it was throwing this below message:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault:11

**My solution:** 
I just imported `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in my category class header file and my bug has been resolved instantly.

**Happy to help you!!**